# What would cause certain buttons to not appear on specific fields using the CKEditor?

Tags: 6, theming, wysiwyg

I am using the CKEditor module for Drupal 6 (not the WYSIWYG module). It's successfully showing the editor on a variety of textareas.

However, on a certain content type the editor is behaving differently on the body field than on other CCK textarea fields. Specifically, several buttons are not appearing on the Body field editor that do appear on other textareas in that same form. Additionally, if I change the button order or appearance in the CKEditor Profile, it does update on the other textarea fields but no the Body field. That field keeps the same button set.

I've tried a variety of things:

1. Deleted and recreated the Global Settings and Profiles for CKEditor
2. Tried to forcefully show the buttons via CSS
3. Confirmed there is no config in sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor.config.js
4. Confirmed no JavaScript is acting on the CSS class wrapper of one of the buttons being hidden.

I'm stumped. What else could be causing CKEditor to load for the body field differently?

Comment: In D6 body fields are treated differently from other textareas (in D7 all textareas including default body text are treated as fields). I'd think that may cause the difference.

Comment: @Paul - Any ideas on how to affect the layout of the editor for body fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I am really, really, blind. I missed an errant CSS style that was hiding a child elements of the CKEditor elements in question.